# In Qtp 12.51, how to select web element from auto-suggest list? Please see attach screenshot

Tags: qtp

After input in company name field, from auto-suggest list I want to select last value in QTP 12.51.

Please see attached image link and waiting for reply.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you are able to loop through all the elements as suggested by Motti, you can check each elements innertext by using:

```
For j = 0 to options.count -1
    If options(j).getRoProperty("innertext") = "<<company Name>>" then
        options(j).click
    end if
 Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a description that matches all the items.

```
Set desc = Description.Create()
desc("html tag").Value = "LI"
desc("class").Value = "^ac_(even|odd)\b.*" ' RegExp
```

Then use `ChildObjects` to get all the matches under the container (I'm assuming you have a test object for that).

```
Set options = Browser("B").Page("P").WebElement("UL").ChildObjects(desc)
```

And click the last element:

```
options(op.Count-1).Click
```

*<sub>Untried code warning</sub>*

Comment: If element position is dynamic, then how to click this particular element?

Comment: @RanjitBhaumik, you need to decide what criteria to chose for selecting the element.